# Custom emoji keyboard for android

Tags: java, android

I have an emoji keyboard application for android. It can send standard emoji with custom emoji image. For send a standard emoji I have no problem.

But when I try to send a custom emoji in a chat/message box (like skype, viber, whatsapp), it open contact list activity, from that activity need to select that person then I can send an image. But I want to send an emoji direct to that person I'm chatting (as standard emoji can).

Is it possible? I use intent and intent filter, but it can't open or direct send to that person I'm chatting. How I can do it? Please help me.